# How to create a realm instance in a service?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to create a Realm instance in my service, but I'm unable to call the `init()`static function, it says cannot resolve symbol init

Comment: Well what is your Realm version?

Answer (score 1):

Create a static `Realmconfiguration` instance in `Application` class (as I quess you want to have same realmconfig for the database in all cases), because this is created when ever a service is created. Than you can initialize `Realm` object in your service with this config.

**In application:**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    feedRealmConfig =  new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("feed")
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    }

public static RealmConfiguration feedRealmConf(){
        return feedRealmConfig;
    }
```

**In service:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    realm = Realm.getInstance(App.feedRealmConf());

    ...
}
```

Don't forget to set in your manifest your application class:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ... 
</application>
```